# Take and save a photo always with the same name on Android

Tags: android, camera, photo

Helo, I'm looking for an Intent user to take a photo and discreetly be stored in a folder but always with the same name, because the resource I'll use to call it from another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/) for save photo in your folder,
and replace below code for save photo with same name every time

from

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

To

```
String timeStamp = "name_of_image";
```

Comment: The solution is perfect, but since I can replace the file, the image is kept and it is not updated every time a new photo is taken

Comment: Okay, so try to delete file with file.delete() and save new file. maybe for some reason your image is not getting save, give me more detail like any exception? so i can help you.